# How to bias BJT using Widlar current source?

Tags: current-source

Here is Widlar Current source driving load:

[image]

It gives almost constant current for wide range of load resistances:

[image]

Here is one circuit involving BJT:

[image]

You can see it is biased using one voltage and one current source.
My question is, how I can use Widlar current source to bias this circuit?
I mean, how should I connect it?

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what you are wanting.

Comment: I'm trying to use Widlar circuit instead of red circle in last image. I thought it's clear :)

Comment: It's clear now!

Comment: It should work as you show it- the compliance of the Widlar source is down to a tenth of a volt or so plus Iout * R1 (top schematic) and you have plenty of voltage at the emitter (nominally about 2V). Of course the Widlar source will be pretty bad if you try to use discrete transistors.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, thanks for reply. Can you please explain this "Of course the Widlar source will be pretty bad if you try to use discrete transistors." ?

Comment: The Widlar current source relies on the matching of the base-emitter current/voltage and thermal characteristics of Q1 and Q2.  While transistors made from one silicon die will match closely, this is not so true for discrete transistors.  That is why the Widlar current source was designed for integrated circuit applications and not discrete circuits.

Comment: @Barry, it means that it will not work good if I build it in practice? Besides Widlar current mirror, I studied Wilson and of cource "basic" simple current mirror. They are assumed also to have matched transistors, so they will also not work good in practice?

Comment: The transistors have to be matched closely and held very close to the same temperature. Difficult outside of an IC, but if you try it either use a pair in the same package or at least connect the two thermally. Usually for discrete designs we add some emitter resistors.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany It's clear. One more thing: Does same apply on darlington pair, for example? It is also assumed that two transistors are matched there, so I guess it would be tricky to build it in practice using discrete transistors, for example using 2n2222.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the collector of Q2 from the 1st circuit to the emitter of the NPN in the 2nd.

Comment: Like this http://s8.postimg.org/3xvdxr25x/widlo.png ?